# Subset pandas dataframe based on datetime in different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I need to subset a dataframe (df1) that has measurements (temp) recorded for every 5 minutes, with datetime as the index.

Dataframe df2, contains data on when there has been an event. 0 is the start of the event and 1 is the end of the event. df2 has a column called date, which is the datetime of the start and end of the respective event. The start and end of all events are recorded to the nearest second.

I want to subset df1 based on the times that there has been an event, using the same datetime format as contained in df1 (temp for every 5 minutes).

In the example below, there has been an event between 00:07:00 and 00:14:00, so I would like df3 to contain df1['temp'] 00:05:00 and 00:10:00. There has also been an event between 00:41:00 and 00:44:00, so i would also like df3 to contain 00:40:00.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'temp' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]},
                    index=pd.date_range('2019-05-02T00:00:00', '2019-05-02T01:00:00', freq='5T'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'event' : [0, 1, 0, 1],
                    'date' : ['2019-05-02-00:07:00', '2019-05-02-00:14:00', '2019-05-02-00:41:00', '2019-05-02-00:44:00']})

df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'result' : [2, 3, 9],
                    'date' :['2019-05-02-00:05:00', '2019-05-02-00:10:00', '2019-05-02-00:40:00']})
```

In my actual work, I have 7 separate df's that each contain different events, which I want to subset df1 and combine, so I end up with a single df that is a subset of all the data in df1, when there has been an event in any of the other 7 df's. df1, in reality, has 37 columns with data that I want to be transferred to the final df3. Once I have the code for the subsetting as above, I was going to merge all of the subset data and delete any duplicates.

Comment: so you want to filter df1 by df2 events but there are 7 "df2"'s?

Comment: Yes please, thats exactly what i want to do

Comment: `here has been an event between 00:07:00 and 00:14:00, so I would like df3 to contain df1['temp'] 00:05:00 and 00:10:00.` - why `00:05:00` ?

Comment: It is not essential that it includes 00:05:00, if it only captured 00:10:00, that would be fine

Comment: So finally need only `1       3  2019-05-02-00:10:00` ? because `00:40:00` not matched too.

Comment: Is there a way that the code can look for any events within the 5 minute period? Some of the events last less than 5 minutes and in these cases, the code might not include them?

Comment: Following your example, if an event starts in a 5-min bin and ends in the following 5-min bin, you want both bins in `df3`. Is this correct?

Comment: Valentino - that is correct, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).
Since you have events which can spawn longer than two bins, you need also a custom resampling function (I found no way to do it better).

```
event_on = 0

def event_tracker(x):
    global event_on
    if len(x) > 0:
        event_on += x.sum()
        return 1
    else:
        if event_on > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

idf2 = df2.set_index('date')
idf2['event'].loc[idf2['event'] == 0] = -1
rbdf2 = idf2.resample('5T').apply(event_tracker)
concatenated = pd.concat([df1, rbdf2], axis=1)
df3 = concatenated.loc[concatenated['event'] > 0.0]
df3 = df3.drop('event', axis=1)
```

Using your sample dataframe, this produces `df3`:

```
                     temp
2019-05-02 00:05:00     2
2019-05-02 00:10:00     3
2019-05-02 00:40:00     9
```

Here dates are set as indexes, if for some reason you need to have them as a column add a final line `df3 = df3.reset_index()`.

Let me explain what I have done above step by step:

- First I define a custom function `event_tracker` for the resampler. It's a bit dirty because it make use of a global variable, but it's the quickest way I found to do it. Basically, the global variable is used to keep track if there is an event ongoing. It returns 0 if the bin has no event ongoing, 1 otherwise.

Then I can go line by line:

1. Setting the column `'date'` as index.
2. Setting the 0 in `idf2` (start of event) to -1. Needed to correctly perform the math in `event_tracker`.
3. Using `resampe`. This function resamples a dataframe with `DatetimeIndex`. I used a resampling of 5 minutes (`'5T'`) to match the bins in `df1` (print `rbdf2` to see it and you will understand). `.apply()` is used to apply `event_tracker` to each bin and get a 0 or 1 as explained before.
4. Using `concat` to concatenate the two dataframes.
5. Selecting only the rows where `event` is > 0, which are the rows where an event is ongoing.
6. Dropping the `'event'` column.

This approach works even if `df2` dates are not ordered.

---

Since you have 7 `df2`s, you need to concatenate them *before* using the above procedure. Simply do:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df21, df22])
```

where `df21` and `df22` are two dataframes with the same structure of your `df2`. If you have seven dataframes, the list given to `concat` have to contain all sevens dataframes: `[df21, df22, df23, ...]`.

Comment: Hi Valentino, thank you for the very detailed response. In my case, the data can range from 30 seconds up to 4 hours or more. The event lenghts are highly variable. What is required to modeify the code, so that it will work with longer events?

Comment: @CairanVanRooyen I edited my answer, now should work also for longer events.

Comment: Hi Valentino. When I get to ```rbdf2 = idf2.resample('5T').apply(event_tracker)``` all my results in my real data are returned as a 1, with no 0's

Comment: Are you sure that there are intervals uncovered by all the seven dataframe `df2`? If at least one cover the time, is counted as 1. Try with just one `df2` to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your given minimal example:

```
# create from df2 a data frame with a 'from' and 'to' column (range data frame)
def df2_like_to_from_to(df2, date_col = 'date'):
    """
    Takes 'event' column, collects all '0' and all '1' event rows
    and concatenates the columns 'date' to a data frame.
    It preserves all other columns from the first ('o') data frame.
    (That is why the code is a little more complicated).
    And renames the date_col column to 'from' and 'to' and puts them upfront.
    """
    df_from = df2[df2.event == 0]
    df_to   = df2[df2.event == 1]
    col_names = [ x if x != date_col else 'from' for x in df2_like.columns]
    df_from_to = pd.concat([df_from.reset_index(), df_to.loc[:, 'date'].reset_index()], axis=1)
    df_from_to = df_from_to.drop(columns=['index'])
    df_from_to.columns = col_names + ['to']
    df_res = df_from_to.loc[:, ['from', 'to'] + [x for x in col_names if x != 'from']]
    return df_res

range_df = df2_like_to_from_to(df2)

# 
#                  from                  to  event
# 0 2019-05-02 00:07:00 2019-05-02 00:14:00      0
# 1 2019-05-02 00:41:00 2019-05-02 00:44:00      0
# 

# filter df1 by its dates overlapping with the range in the range data frame
def filter_by_overlap(dates, df, df_from_to, from_to_col=['from', 'to']):
    """
    Filters df rows by overlaps of given dates (one per row) with da data frame
    which contains ranges (column names to be given by 'from_to_col' - first for 'from' and second for 'to' values).
    The dates are used to build a pseudo-interval which then is searched for
    any overlap with the ranges in the ranges data frame.
    The df is subsetted for any overlap and returned.
    """
    ranges_from_to = df_from_to.loc[:, from_to_col].apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*x),  axis=1)
    ranges_date = [pd.Interval(x, x) for x in dates] # pseudo range for data points
    selector = [any(x.overlaps(y) for y in ranges_from_to) for x in ranges_date]
    return df.loc[selector, :]

filter_by_overlap(df1.index, df1, range_df)
# first argument: the data list/column for which overlaps should be searched
# second argument: the to-be-filtered data frame
# third argument: the range data frame which should select the dates (first argument)

# output:
#                      temp
# 2019-05-02 00:10:00     3
```